# how to store a dictionary as a json file and edit it?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a function that creates a dictionary based on the user's input:

```
def store_data(user_inp):

list_of_letters = list(user_inp)
list_of_colons = []
nested_dict = {}

for letter in list_of_letters:
    if letter == ':':
        list_of_colons.append(letter)

if len(list_of_colons) == 2:
    str1 = ''.join(list_of_letters)
    list2 = str1.split(':')
    main_key = list2[0]
    nested_key = list2[1]
    value = list2[2]
    if main_key not in storage:
        storage[main_key] = nested_dict
        nested_dict[nested_key] = value
        print(storage, '\n', 'successfully saved!')
    elif main_key in storage:
        if nested_key in storage[main_key]:
            print('this item is already saved: \n', storage)
        else:
            storage[main_key][nested_key] = value
            print(storage, '\n', 'successfully saved!')

    jf = json.dumps(storage)
    with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(jf)
        f.close()
```

What i'm trying to do is to store the final dictionary somewhere permanent.
I tried this at the end of my function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
jf = json.dumps(storage)
    with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(jf)
        f.close()
```

How can I store the final dictionary so it's permanent but still editable?

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to work"_ What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can save it to a `.json` file as you did. After that, you can still edit the variable that you pasted. So you could create a thread that auto-saves every 10 minutes or so by invoking

```
jf = json.dumps(storage)
    with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(jf)
```

PS: You don't need to care about `f.close()` if you are using `with open(...)` :)

If you can't tell what is happening where I highly suggest printing the current state of `storage` ***before*** entering a new `if` clause

I'm sorry but I am unable to debug your code because there are to many variables undefined...

Comment: worked great! One question, will it be ok to store passwords and stuff? I will be the only one using this program. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Of cause you can store passwords and sensitive data. But if you do so, be sure to store them properly. If it's just for your private application, you may store them in plain-text, but as soon as other people store sensitive data on your server, you should definitely encrypt/hash them :) Do you accept my answer, or isn't it what you needed?

Comment: This is what i needed, thanks again!!!!